# PostgreSQL querying JSONB column which has string value rather than JSON object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

How can I make a query based on the value of a JSONB column when the column contains string values rather than JSON objects. Example:

```
my_table (
 id int
 key varchar(128)
 val jsonb
)
```

Records are:

```
1,'name','My test app'
2,'name','Another test app'
3,'name','{"value": "This is a proper jsonb value"}'
```

So I want to get the first record in some way similar to:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE val = 'My test app'`

The problem is that  since `val` is of type jsonb, this type of comparison isn't allowed (since it expects you to select something from a json object value). How can I workaround this?

Comment: How did you even get those non JSON values in the `jsonb` column? That [doesn't work for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=18779735ac367b85ae82397165670ad2). Please provide working DDL and DML to reproduce your situation.

Comment: I managed to insert it with this SQL Go library: https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#usage with the `NamedExec` functionality. Anyway, your schema looks correct and after trying to insert it with sql command it doesn't allow me to do it. But for some reason this library bypasses the validation for the jsonb value.

Comment: OK, then go find out what that library was doing on the SQL level to get that situation and [edit] the question to include your findings.

Comment: As @stickybit said: Your first two records are not valid. So, it's not possible to answer this question. You must check what the table really look like (what your library really created, maybe it created a type text column instead of a type json).